# Check if coordinate in selected area

Tags: geometry, coordinates, area

I have 4 coordinates of area: **x1,y1** ... etc. And have one more position **x0,y0**.

How to check if my coordinate in selected area?

[image: Area and point coordinates]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine if a point is within a quadrilateral](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922027/how-to-determine-if-a-point-is-within-a-quadrilateral)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will explain you how to check that (x0,y0) lies "below" the line through (x1,y1) and (x2,y2). Essentially, you want that the vector (x0-x1,y0-y1) points "to the right" of (x2-x1, y2-y1). This is equivalent to saying that the matrix

```
x0-x1      y0-y1

x2-x1      y2-y1
```

has a negative determinant. So your condition becomes

```
(x0-x1)(y2-y1) < (y0-y1)(x2-x1).
```

You get such a condition for any line bounding the area.

Comment: Didn't think about checking for every line separately.  Interesting solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let

```
A = {x1, y1}
B = {x2, y2}
C = {x3, x3}
D = {x4, x4}
```

First, make sure that points form a polynomial and are not in straight line. This can be done by comparing the `direction(AB) != direction(AC) != direction(AD)` where AB, AC, AD are directional vectors.

To make sure that certain point `P = {x0, y0}` lies within the polygon `ABCD`, it is sufficient to check that `sign(AC X AP) == sign(CD X CP) == sign(DB X DP) == sign(BA X BP)`.

```
AC: Directional vector A -> C
AP: Directional vector A -> P
.
. so on!
.
X: Cross product
sign: sign of cross product (+ or -)
```

It is only required to compare the sign of direction not the magnitude.