# Determine if a 2D point is within a quadrilateral

Tags: javascript, algorithm, geometry

I'm working on a JS program which I need to have determine if points are within four corners in a coordinate system.

Could somebody point me in the direction of an answer?

I'm looking at what I think is called a convex quadrilateral. That is, four pretty randomly chosen corner positions with all angles smaller than 180°.

Thanks.

Comment: I tried the inpolygon methon used here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922027/how-to-determine-if-a-point-is-within-a-quadrilateral?rq=1), but it doesn't work. It gives me "Cannot call method 'inpolygon' of undefined".
`if (Math.inpolygon(5,6,[1,22,13,1],[1,1,21,31])){
                return "yep";
            }`

Comment: and why you cannot just compare coordinates? can you describe the problem closer? what are points? corner?

Comment: I have tons of quite randomly generated quadrilaterals. Then I need to check wether some (also quite randomly generated) points are "available" or already occupied by a quadrilateral.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two relatively simple approaches. The first approach is to draw a ray from the point to "infinity" (actually, to any point outside the polygon) and count how many sides of the polygon the ray intersects. The point is inside the polygon if and only if the count is odd.

The second approach is to go around the polygon in order and for every pair of vertices v<sub>i</sub> and v<sub>i+1</sub> (wrapping around to the first vertex if necessary), compute the quantity (x - x<sub>i</sub>) * (y<sub>i+1</sub> - y<sub>i</sub>) - (x<sub>i+1</sub> - x<sub>i</sub>) * (y - y<sub>i</sub>). If these quantities all have the same sign, the point is inside the polygon. (These quantities are the Z component of the cross product of the vectors (v<sub>i+1</sub> - v<sub>i</sub>) and (p - v<sub>i</sub>). The condition that they all have the same sign is the same as the condition that p is on the same side (left or right) of every edge.)

Both approaches need to deal with the case that the point is exactly on an edge or on a vertex. You first need to decide whether you want to count such points as being inside the polygon or not. Then you need to adjust the tests accordingly. Be aware that slight numerical rounding errors can give a false answer either way. It's just something you'll have to live with.

Since you have a convex quadrilateral, there's another approach. Pick any three vertices and compute the [barycentric coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system) of the point and of the fourth vertex with respect to the triangle formed by the three chosen vertices. If the barycentric coordinates of the point are all positive and all less than the barycentric coordinates of the fourth vertex, then the point is inside the quadrilateral.

P.S. Just found a nice page [here](http://erich.realtimerendering.com/ptinpoly/) that lists quite a number of strategies. Some of them are very interesting.

Comment: I don't quite see how I am to draw a ray like in the first approach without involving a lot lot lot of (unnecessary) computation, but i reckon I'll get it to work with the second one. Thanks!

Comment: @Henrik - Just pick a point on the X axis that is further out than the max X coordinate of the four vertices. The ray can then go from your test point to the point on the X axis. (You can use the Y axis equally well, of course.) Just remember that you need to test for the intersection of the line _segments_, not the lines.

Comment: @Henrik - If you're going with the second approach, be aware that I had a typo in the formula. It's now fixed. (I had used 0 instead of i as a subscript in a couple of places.)

Comment: Your second approach is computing if the point is in the intersection of the four halfspaces formed by the sides of the quadrilateral. It's a bit of a convoluted formula :)

Comment: @AndrewMao - I don't know about convoluted; it's just a cross product.

Comment: I meant to say, you can explain the formula that way instead of just plopping it out like that :)

Comment: @AndrewMao - Nah. I'm a programmer. For programmers, you plop out code, you don't explain things. :)

Comment: you should *always* explain your formula. Being a programmer isn't an adequate excuse.

Comment: @darksky - I hope you realize that my comment was supposed to be a joke!

Comment: Well, joking or not, there is no explanation. I don't mean to be rude, but

Comment: @darksky - Fair enough. I added an explanation.

Comment: Much better. It always helps to understand what an algorithm is doing as opposed to just see how it's implemented.

Comment: So if there are 4 points - (x1,y1), (x2,y2),(x3,y3) and (x4,y4), I should consider the signs of these 4 quantities, right?

`(x - x1) * (y2 - y1) - (x2 - x1) * (y - y1)`, 
`(x - x2) * (y3 - y2) - (x3 - x2) * (y - y2)`,
`(x - x3) * (y4 - y3) - (x4 - x3) * (y - y3)` and `(x - x4) * (y1 - y4) - (x1 - x4) * (y - y4)` ? I am a bit confused about the wrapping, so asking.

Comment: Thanks Ted. However I have a problem. In my case, I am dealing with coordinates on a micro-scale, and even if some points lie outside the quadrilateral, as long as it is very close I want to make it look like as if it lies inside. So I need some baselining instead of just checking all positive or all negative. Can you recommend some approach for the same?

Comment: @SexyBeast - Hm. My first instinct would be to expand the quadrilateral by the desired tolerance before testing the points. This could be done by scaling the quadrilateral around the centroid of its vertices. (I'm assuming here that the quadrilateral is convex.) Or perhaps a more detailed analysis of what you want to accomplish might suggest a better expansion approach.

Comment: Sure Ted. So I have a series of quadrilateral side by side, which I want to merge. The quadrilaterals are small, so even if some vertices of some quads lie slightly outside the uber quadrilateral formed by joining the leftmost points of the first quad and the rightmost points of the last quad, we want to include it. Of course if any quad's any vertex lies substantially outside the uber quad, we don't want to merge them. So how do I find that whether any of the vertices of any of the quads to be merged lies substantially outside the uber quad? We can assume that the quads are convex.

Comment: @SexyBeast - I don't understand your setup enough to answer. The process for forming the uber quad is unclear to me; perhaps a picture would help. Also, the term "substantially outside" needs to be pinned down to something definite that can translate into a decision algorithm. Anyway, this topic is too much for a comment thread. Why not post a question, including relevant details of the application that's giving rise to this problem?

Comment: Yep, thought as much. :) Will do!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use winding, or the ray trace method.

With winding, you can determine whether any point is inside any shape built with line segments.

Basically, you take the cross product of each line segment with the point, then add up all the results. That's the way I did it to decide if a star was in a constellation, given a set of constellation lines. I can see that there are other ways..

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon

There must be some code for this in a few places.

Answer (score 0):

It is MUCH easier to see if a point lies within a triangle.

Any quadrilateral can be divided into two triangles.

If the point is in any of the two triangles that comprise the quadrilateral, then the point is inside the quadrilateral.