# How to check if an X, Y Point is within a square made up of 4 X, Y Points?

Tags: for-loop, f#, geometry, point

I am trying to check to see if a part of the square is present, if so I will do something like plot X, Y to a bitmap.

The difficult part is, the square does not have to be perfect. It could be skewed. The square I made in my code below is an example of that. I want to go through a loop for X then Y and see if the points are within the square. Eventually I want to be able to use the Z coordinate to determine how close the point is to decide how bright/dark the pixel on the bitmap will be.

This is the code that I have right now:

```
open System

type Point =
    { X : int
      Y : int
      Z : int }

type Square =
    { P1 : Point
      P2 : Point
      P3 : Point
      P4 : Point }

let square =
    { P1 = { X = 10; Y = 10; Z = 0 }
      P2 = { X = 90; Y = 10; Z = 0 }
      P3 = { X = 20; Y = 80; Z = 0 }
      P4 = { X = 80; Y = 80; Z = 0 } }

for x in 0 .. 99 do
    for y in 0 .. 99 do
        // do something
```

Comment: This was asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922027/how-to-determine-if-a-point-is-within-a-quadrilateral),
It's a subset of a popular problem named [point in a polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon). By the way, the shape you described is called a quadrilateral.

Comment: I looked at the post and figured out how to calculate the areas of the four triangles then sum them, but I'm still stuck on calculating the area of a quadrilateral. Could you help with that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine if a point is within a quadrilateral](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922027/how-to-determine-if-a-point-is-within-a-quadrilateral)

Comment: this shouldbe a comment,not an answer

Comment: I couldn't comment before though, as I'm new.

Comment: @Alanay 
You can find a formula here :
http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/docs/reference/CRC-formulas/node23.html

Use the one with the length of the edges and diagonals which you can calculate easily given the coordinates for each point.